# How to duplicate VRM models properly with react-three-fiber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I've been working on a 3D Web project using following libraries mainly

- react
- react-three-fiber
- @react-three/drei
- three-vrm
- @zoom/videosdk
- socket.io

What I'm trying to achieve is, render 3D VRM models which represents each participant in the connected room using zoom sdk and socket.io, and lipsync each 3D VRM models with participant's mic volume.

The lipsync function is working now but, it synchronizes all 3D VRM models in the room, and not the only certain Model representing current speaker.